# Execute OpenShift pipelines on an external Jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, openshift, openshift-origin

I'm new to OpenShift and not sure if my use case is even possible. I have an OpenShift cluster installed and all, and I'm trying to integrate it with an existing Jenkins server that lives outside the cluster, just so we can be able to create OpenShift pipelines and execute them there.

Any suggestions on how to proceed? So far I have disabled the auto-provisioning of jenkins in my OC cluster and configured the "jenkins" service to point to the external jenkins master. Now I'm creating pipelines on Openshift and expecting to see respective jobs in Jenkins, but the sync is not happening, as I'm not seeing any jobs getting created in the jenkins server.

Regards,
Mali

Comment: And here is the error i'm seeing in the jenkins logs. Not sure why the OpenShift Jenkins Sync is not working properly in my case.

Comment: The error i'm seeing in the jenkins logs:

io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.ImageStreamWatcher$1@3988164c failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.fabric8.openshift.client.dsl.internal.OpenShiftOperation
 at io.fabric8.openshift.client.DefaultOpenShiftClient.imageStreams(DefaultOpenShiftClient.java:332)
 at io.fabric8.jenkins.openshiftsync.ImageStreamWatcher$1.doRun(ImageStreamWatcher.java:65)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use openshift sync plugin and configure the same to sync your buildconfigs between external jenkins and openshift. This document [Integrate external jenkins with openshift](http://playbooks-rhtconsulting.rhcloud.com/playbooks/continuous_delivery/external-jenkins-integration.html)  should help you with futher details.